# Or command in ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

Unfortunately, my data that is in a bad shape. Therefore I have to do a lot of adjustments, which I cannot do, yet. My `test.data` looks like this:

```
a <- c("Arthur", "Markus", "Kommission fuer Wirtschaft und Abgaben", "Meyer", "Hans", "Delegation XY")
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
testdata <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I want a new column `c`which contains the values of `b` only if `a` contains the words "Kommission" or "Delegation".

In a first step I tried this:

```
testdata$c <- ifelse((grepl('Kommission',testdata$a)==TRUE), testdata$b,NA)
```

This works well. My problem is that I need the value of `b` for "Delegation" too. 
With

```
testdata$c <- ifelse((grepl('Delegation',testdata$a)==TRUE), testdata$b,NA)
```

I only override the previous command. In the end `testdata` should look like this:

```
a                                      b  c 
Arthur                                 1 NA
Markus                                 2 NA
Kommission fuer Wirtschaft und Abgaben 3  3
Meyer                                  4 NA
Hans                                   5 NA
Delegation XY                          6  6
```

Can I connect several "or-statements" in `ifelse`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes you can, with `|`.

Comment: `|` is the OR operator in R. Use it to specify two logical conditions in the first argument to `ifelse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the answer contains `|`.

```
testdata$c <- ifelse((grepl('Kommission',testdata$a)==TRUE) | grepl('Delegation',testdata$a)==TRUE, testdata$b,NA)
```

Comment: The `==TRUE` parts are unnecessary here since the expression will only evaluate when `TRUE` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
testdata$c <- ifelse(testdata$a %in% c("Kommission","Delegation"),testdata$b,NA)
```